# I am getting ORA-12154 "TNS: couldn't resolve the connect identifier specified". Issue with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client

Tags: asp.net, .net, oracle, oracle-manageddataaccess

I am getting ORA-12154 "TNS: couldn't resolve the connect identifier specified". I am replacing Oracle.DataAccess.Client with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client. I am using windows10 64 bit. It works well with DataAccess.Client and on another machine. Is something wrong with OS? Your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I used nuget package manager to reference the dll

Comment: @mjw, ODP.NET Managed Drive does not depend on 32/64 bit settings, it works for both. Most likely this is not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I assume ODP.NET Managed Driver does not find your `tnsnames.ora` (resp. `sqlnet.ora`, `ldap.ora`, etc.) file. Search pattern of `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` is different to search patter used by `Oracle.DataAccess`

According [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E63277_01/win.121/e63268/InstallManagedConfig.htm#ODPNT8161) the ODP.NET Managed Driver Configuration resolves alias in this order:

1. data source alias in the `dataSources` section under `<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>` section in the .NET config file (i.e. `machine.config`, `web.config`, `user.config`).
2. data source alias in the `tnsnames.ora` file at the location specified by `TNS_ADMIN` in the .NET config file. Locations can consist of either absolute or relative directory paths.
3. data source alias in the `tnsnames.ora` file present in the same directory as the `.exe`.

As you see, unlike `Oracle.DataAccess` it does **not** read `TNS_ADMIN` value from Registry or `TNS_ADMIN` Environment variable.

However, regarding `TNS_ADMIN` Environment variable I am not sure if this is a bug in documentation - maybe I will test this by time.

Comment: data sources alias in the datasource section in web config file. Application is not getting data source info from web config datasource section.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. There is tns_admin entry under  section in machine.config file and it was pointing to tnsnames.ora file on Oracle_Home. I commented the section and its working fine. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way in my case.
Set ORACLE_HOME environment variable in application startup method
without any changes or settings in web.config

```
var oracleHome = GetOracleHome(); // Find registry...
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ORACLE_HOME", oracleHome);
```